# Ajax rss feed not working on localhost

Tags: ajax, rss

I'm trying to get the following code from w3schools to work oh my localhost through IIS. When I run it, I can see that it is trying to retrieve the requested rss feed but unfortunately it never executes. It only allows me to see the options to chose from but never displays them.

Many thanks in advance for any help.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            function showRSS(str)
            {
                if (str.length==0)
                  {
                  document.getElementById("rssOutput").innerHTML="";
                  return;
                  }
                if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
                  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
                  }
                else
                  {// code for IE6, IE5
                  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                  }
                xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
                  {
                  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
                    {
                    document.getElementById("rssOutput").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
                    }
                  }
            xmlhttp.open("GET","getrss.php?q="+str,true);
            xmlhttp.send();
        }
        </script>
    </head>
<body>

    <form>
        <select onchange="showRSS(this.value)">
            <option value="">Select an RSS-feed:</option>
            <option value="Google">Google News</option>
            <option value="MSNBC">MSNBC News</option>
        </select>
    </form>
    <br>
    <div id="rssOutput">RSS-feed will be listed here...</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

And the php file

```
<?php
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
    //get the q parameter from URL
    $q=$_GET["q"];

    //find out which feed was selected
    if($q=="Google")
          {
          $xml=("http://news.google.com/news?ned=us&topic=h&output=rss");
          }
        elseif($q=="MSNBC")
          {
      $xml=("http://rss.msnbc.msn.com/id/3032091/device/rss/rss.xml");
      }

    $xmlDoc = new DOMDocument();
    $xmlDoc->load($xml);

    //get elements from "<channel>"
    $channel=$xmlDoc->getElementsByTagName('channel')->item(0);
    $channel_title = $channel->getElementsByTagName('title')
    ->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
    $channel_link = $channel->getElementsByTagName('link')
    ->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
    $channel_desc = $channel->getElementsByTagName('description')
    ->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;

    //output elements from "<channel>"
    echo("<p><a href='" . $channel_link
      . "'>" . $channel_title . "</a>");
    echo("<br>");
    echo($channel_desc . "</p>");

    //get and output "<item>" elements
    $x=$xmlDoc->getElementsByTagName('item');
    for ($i=0; $i<=2; $i++)
      {
      $item_title=$x->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('title')
      ->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
      $item_link=$x->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('link')
      ->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
      $item_desc=$x->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('description')
      ->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;

      echo ("<p><a href='" . $item_link
      . "'>" . $item_title . "</a>");
      echo ("<br>");
      echo ($item_desc . "</p>");
      }
?>
```

Comment: Sorry one small edit here, I can run the the code in XAMPP but not in IIS and I'm mostly curious as to why.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is a cross platform problem.

If you're using Chrome, try opening it like this :

```
chrome.exe -allow-file-access-from-files
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the html code does this:

- Checks if an RSS-feed is selected; **then**
- Creates the function to be executed when the server response is ready; **then**
- **Sends the request off to a file on the server**,

Are you using this on your mac? I think that the localhost cannot give a server response in os x. Or, you have to unlock something using terminal to make it work.

This code is correct because it does work on my server.